# Given $y^T A y \geq \mu \| y \|_2^2$ how to find $\mu$ and restrictions on $A$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a matrix $A$, what properties must $A$ have to satisfy a bound like

$$
y^T A y \geq \mu \| y \|_2^2
$$

For some positive constant $\mu$?

---

My instinct is that $\mu$ must be smaller than the smallest eigenvalue of $A$, but I am not sure if this is correct or if my intuition is wrong.

Furthermore, how could I find $\mu$ given a specific $A$? (Assuming $A$ can satisfy the bound).

---

Edit:

For the specific problem I am interested in, we can assume $A$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then you can take $\mu$ to be the smallest modulus of an eigenvalue.

Comment: $A+A^T$ must be invertible

Comment: @copper.hat Where can I find more information about this?

Comment: Symmetric matrices can be diagonalised.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah but I think that bound is not true if $A$ is not positive definite.

Comment: @Y.S.: And you think that because...?

Comment: take a 2 D example $A = U\Lambda U^T$ where $U = [u_1,u_2]$ and $\Lambda = \mathrm{diag}(p,n)$, $n \leq 0$. Then pick $y = u_2$. Then $y^TAy = n < 0$.

Comment: @Y.S.: You are correct. Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah it's not super obvious when looking at the minimum eigenvalue. For the bound going the other way I think you're right, though (with the maximum modulus.)

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, you want to find $\mu$ where
$$
\mu := \min_{y\neq 0 } \frac{y^TAy}{y^Ty}.
$$

Now take the eigenvalue decomposition of $A = U\Lambda U^T$, where $U^TU = UU^T = I$. Then we can do a change of variables $v = U^Ty \iff y = Uv$ and equivalently arrive at 
$$
\mu := \min_{v\neq 0 } \frac{v^T\Lambda v}{v^Tv}.
$$
where $v^T\Lambda v = \sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda_{ii}v_i^2$. Now this becomes kind of a "weight placement" problem: how do we design $v$ so that it puts the most weight on the smallest value $\Lambda_{ii}$? To make this even more obvious, I'm going to introduce another change of variables: $z_i = (v_i^2 / \|v\|_2^2)$. Now the problem becomes
$$
\mu := \min_{z > 0, \sum_i z_i = 1 } \sum_{i}\Lambda_{ii} z_i.
$$
The solution to this "weight placement" problem is to put all the "mass" of $z_i$ on the smallest value of $\Lambda_{ii}$. That is, if all the values of $\Lambda_{ii}$ are distinct, then
$$
z_i = \begin{cases}
1, & \Lambda_{ii} = \min_j\Lambda_{jj}\\
0, & \text{else.} 
\end{cases}
$$
(If the values are not distinct then you can just pick one such minimal $\Lambda_{ii}$ value and get the same result.)

Thus, $\mu = \min_i\Lambda_{ii}$.

Note that as pointed out, $\mu \geq 0$ only if $A$ is PSD, e.g. $\min_i\Lambda_{ii} \geq 0$.